# DistributeDefinitions not working for compiled functions

Tags: bugs, parallelization, compile

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 9.0.0**

---

I'm having trouble with parallel evaluation of compiled functions. Here is a simple example illustrating the problem:

```
testwm = Compile[ {{x, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
    Module[ {sum, inc}, sum = 1.0; inc = 1.0; 
    Do[inc = inc*x/i; sum = sum + inc, {i, n}]; sum], 
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM"];

Map[(testwm[1.5, 2000000] + $KernelID) &, 
  Range[2 $ProcessorCount]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
==> {1.4290817, {4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 
  4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169}}
*)
ParallelMap[(testwm[1.5, 2000000] + $KernelID) &, 
  Range[2 $ProcessorCount]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
==> {1.4210813, {10.4817, 10.4817, 9.48169, 9.48169, 8.48169, 
  8.48169, 7.48169, 7.48169, 6.48169, 6.48169, 5.48169, 5.48169}}
*)
ParallelEvaluate[testwm = Compile[ {{x, _Real}, {n, _Integer}},
        Module[ {sum, inc}, sum = 1.0; inc = 1.0; 
      Do[inc = inc*x/i; sum = sum + inc, {i, n}]; sum], 
     CompilationTarget -> "WVM"];];
ParallelMap[(testwm[1.5, 2000000] + $KernelID) &, 
  Range[2 $ProcessorCount], DistributedContexts -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
==> {0.2760158, {10.4817, 10.4817, 9.48169, 9.48169, 8.48169, 
  8.48169, 7.48169, 7.48169, 6.48169, 6.48169, 5.48169, 5.48169}}
*)
ParallelEvaluate[ClearAll[testwm]];
```

From this example it's clear that `DistributeDefinitons` is not working properly, since `ParallelMap` offered no speed-up. It does not help even if I add an explicit call to `DistributeDefinitons`. If I compile the function on each kernel, then I get the expected speed increase.

**Is this (another) bug or am I doing something wrong?**

I'm using mma 8.0.1 on win7 64 bit.

PS: for non compiled functions everything works as expected:

```
testnc[x_, n_] := 
  Module[ {sum, inc}, sum = 1.0; inc = 1.0; 
   Do[inc = inc*x/i; sum = sum + inc, {i, n}]; sum];
Map[(testnc[1.5, 10000] + $KernelID) &, 
  Range[2 $ProcessorCount]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
==> {0.5660324, {4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 
  4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169, 4.48169}}
*)
ParallelMap[(testnc[1.5, 10000] + $KernelID) &, 
  Range[2 $ProcessorCount]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
==> {0.1210069, {10.4817, 10.4817, 9.48169, 9.48169, 8.48169, 
  8.48169, 7.48169, 7.48169, 6.48169, 6.48169, 5.48169, 5.48169}}
*)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your timing difference. The very first time you run `ParallelMap`, there is a time lag to launch the kernels. After that, I get the speed-up from `ParallelMap` of the kind that I would expect (roughly 5-fold on 6 cores). I am on Win 7 64 bit M8.0.

Comment: if I try `DistributeDefinitions[testwm];ParallelTable[{$KernelID, OwnValues[testwm]}, {i, 1, 4}]`, it appears that the definitions do get distributed

Comment: @acl [Not on my machine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Ahj.png). I ran this on a fresh kernel. Do you have 8.0.1?

Comment: 8.0.1, yes. I have the same timing as you do, I was simply saying that if you do what I say, it does appear that the slave kernels know about the functions. Also `t = Compile[{}, $KernelID]; ParallelTable[t[], {i, 1, 4}]`

Comment: I can confirm your findings on 8.0.4. `DistributeDefinitions` doesn't seem to like `CompiledFunctions`: after compiling, try `DistributeDefinitions[testwm]; ParallelEvaluate@HoldForm[testwm // Evaluate]` and you'll see the slave kernels still don't know about `testwm`. In contrast, `With[{testwmcopy = testwm}, ParallelEvaluate[testwm = testwmcopy]];` works. Don't have time to look into this now but I suspect a bug in `DistributeDefinitions` (it wouldn't be the first...). FWIW behaviour in version 7 is as it should be.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks for workaround with `With`. (So that I don't have to compile on each kernel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick workaround, so that one does not have to manually track which `CompiledFunction`s to distribute.

```
ClearAll[CompiledFunctionNames];
CompiledFunctionNames[pattern_] := 
  Select[Names["Global`*"], 
   MatchQ[Evaluate[Symbol@#], _CompiledFunction] &];

ClearAll[DistributeCompiledFunction]
DistributeCompiledFunction[name_] := 
  With[{copy = Symbol[name]}, 
   ParallelEvaluate[
    If[ MatchQ[Evaluate[Symbol@name], _Symbol],(*Print["Setting ",
     name];*)Evaluate[Symbol[name]] = copy]]];

ClearAll[DistributeCompiledFunctions];
DistributeCompiledFunctions[pattern_] := 
  DistributeCompiledFunction /@ CompiledFunctionNames[pattern];
```

and some rudimentary tests:

```
testwm = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{sum, inc}, sum = 1.0; inc = 1.0;
    Do[inc = inc*x/i; sum = sum + inc, {i, n}]; sum], 
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM"];
testwm1 = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{sum, inc}, sum = 1.0; inc = 1.0;
    Do[inc = inc*x/i; sum = sum + inc, {i, n}]; sum], 
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM"];
a = 5; (*a non compiled symbol -- will not get destributed*)
(*see which compiled functions are in the current context*)
CompiledFunctionNames["Global`*"] 
DistributeCompiledFunctions["Global`*"];
(*distributing twice does not override previous definition*)
DistributeCompiledFunctions["Global`*"]; 
(*check if it worked*)
DeleteDuplicates@ParallelEvaluate@HoldForm[testwm // Evaluate]
DeleteDuplicates@ParallelEvaluate@HoldForm[testwm1 // Evaluate]
DeleteDuplicates@ParallelEvaluate@HoldForm[a // Evaluate]
ParallelMap[(testwm[1.5, 2000000] + $KernelID) &, 
      Range[2 $ProcessorCount], 
  DistributedContexts -> None] // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelEvaluate[ClearAll[testwm, testwm1]];
```

Disclaimer: I have not yet tested this extensively.